# CSS3 transofrms on a div changed by a javascript function

Tags: javascript, css, transition

i have a div in which i have a button linked to a javascript function that will toggle a textarea. When the button is clicked the div size instantly changes. I tried adding transition effects to the div but there is no smooth change in size (height to be more specific).
My question is: is there any way in wich i can make the div to be resized smoothly?

Comment: Are you already using jQuery or some other library? Or are you using raw Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

use `.animate()` - http://api.jquery.com/animate/

If you can provide some code i'd be happy to explain this in greater detail.

I've coded a quick example for you - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/eaBgT/

Answer (score 0):

Don't just a height transition, use a scaley transform from 0 to 1. This should be smoother.